# React - how to rerender component after POST data to database (mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, post, get

I'm building app which sends data to my database (mongodb). In ComponentDidMount I fetch data from this database, save them in this.state and show them in frontend. Next, I want to add another single data to this database from form in frontend. For now it works fine, couse this single data is added to database, but I have to refresh page to see new-added data.

So, I'm wondering how to show dynamically in frontend newly added item to database.

My first thoughts were something with component lifecycle, or maybe some function which fetch data after submit form, but this won't work.

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Users from './Users';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            users: [],
            group: '',
            password: '',
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            dateOfBirth: '',
            listOfUserGroups: ''
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/users')
          .then(res => {
            const users = res.data;
            this.setState({ users });
            console.log(this.state.users);
          })
    }

    handleGroupChange = e => {
        this.setState({ group: e.target.value });
    }

    handlePasswordChange = e => {
        this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
    }

    handleFirstNameChange = e => {
        this.setState({ firstName: e.target.value });
    }

    handleLastNameChange = e => {
        this.setState({ lastName: e.target.value });
    }

    handleDateOfBirthChange = e => {
        this.setState({ dateOfBirth: e.target.value });
    }

    handleListOfUserGroupsChange = e => {
        this.setState({ listOfUserGroups: e.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newUser = {
            group: this.state.group,
            password: this.state.password,
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
            dateOfBirth: this.state.dateOfBirth,
            listOfUserGroups: this.state.listOfUserGroups
        };

        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/users', newUser)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Saved');
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log(this.state.firstName);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <div className='mainWrapper'>
                  <form className='formStyle' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                      <label>Group</label>
                      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleGroupChange} />

                      <label>Password</label>
                      <input type="text" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} />

                      <label>First name</label>
                      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange} />

                      <label>Last name</label>
                      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleLastNameChange} />

                      <label>Date of birth</label>
                      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleDateOfBirthChange} />

                      <label>List of user groups</label>
                      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleListOfUserGroupsChange} />

                      <button type="submit">Add</button>
                  </form>
                </div>

                <Users users={this.state.users} />

                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>{this.state.group}</li>
                        <li>{this.state.password}</li>
                        <li>{this.state.firstName}</li>
                        <li>{this.state.lastName}</li>
                        <li>{this.state.dateOfBirth}</li>
                        <li>{this.state.listOfUserGroups}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: I would add the new user to your state. In this progress, your component will render again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just push to the array to make the update to the state and it will rerender.

```
 handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newUser = {
        group: this.state.group,
        password: this.state.password,
        firstName: this.state.firstName,
        lastName: this.state.lastName,
        dateOfBirth: this.state.dateOfBirth,
        listOfUserGroups: this.state.listOfUserGroups
    };

    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/users', newUser)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('Saved');
            this.setState(prevState=>({
              users: [newUser, ...prevState.users]
            }))
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(this.state.firstName);
        });
}
```

Or if necessary, you can push to the state before the `axios` call and revert back only if the call fails. This is called [Optimistic UI](https://uxplanet.org/optimistic-1000-34d9eefe4c05)

Note: You can handle multiple input change like [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs)

Comment: Thanks Boy With Silver Wings !! You helped me a lot! That's what I was searching for. Works perfect. Also stuff with multiple input change. Now code is more friendly ;)

Comment: This doesn't work if multiple users can edit the user-groups. After the state change, the user will get this illusion that their list on the UI has been updated, but the DB has additional values entered by another user, those won't be reflected.

Comment: of course, managing stale data on the application is a hard problem. But that isn't one that is covered in this answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your state on your post response. By default, when your component’s state or props change, your component will re-render.

Solution 1 :

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/users', newUser)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data); //need to be your new "user" from server response
        //You can update your "users" state there with add new user in your state
        });
```

Solution 2:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/users', newUser)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data); //need to be your new "user" from server response
            //You can send your "get" request again to update your component state
            axios.get('http://localhost:3001/users')
                .then(res => {
                const users = res.data;
                this.setState({ users });
                console.log(this.state.users);
            })
        });
```

Comment: So you mean add ComponentDidUpdate or in handleSubmit function change this.state which will force component to update?

Comment: Solution 2 is the best solution if you don't have a lot of data

Comment: I did. Thanks Sam for your solutions too. I'll keep them in mind couse I tried them and they work as well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can add the standard function `this.forceUpdate()` after you post the data to rerender the component

Comment: Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() ! See : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: isn't this.forceUpdate() a "hard code" or some kind of anti-pattern?

Comment: I know, but in this case is complete contrelled. You can also do a function that after the post fetch the user again or put the user inside the state